# ListView Item click opens new fragment error

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I have a ListView. If I click on the first element in the listview (which is at position 0) I want that a new fragment opens. But I am getting this error

> No view found for id 0x7f0d00a8 (com.example.user.app:id/frag5) for fragment Fragment6{11a5bdd4 #0 id=0x7f0d00a8}

I am trying this since days but I am not getting what I'm doing wrong. I really just want  that Fragment6 opens when I click on my ListView Item. That's it. I am really surprised how difficult this is in contrast to other things. I started developing apps 6 months ago and I handled a lot of things but here I am a bit desperated. I hope you can help me out here.

Here is my ListView Method:

```
 // ListView Item Click Listener
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            // ListView Clicked item index
            int itemPosition     = position;

            // ListView Clicked item value
            String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

            // Show Alert
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Position :"+itemPosition+"  ListItem : " +itemValue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

           if(position==0 ) {
               Fragment6 frag6 = null;
               frag6 = new Fragment6();
               FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
               fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                       .replace(R.id.frag5, frag6)
                       .commit();
           }
        }

    });
```

And here is my Fragment6. java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

 public class Fragment6 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragmentdescrip6, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
```

}

Here is the according layout called `fragmentdescrip6`

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/frag6"

>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textfrag6label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Header:"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#FFFF4444"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textfrag6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textfrag6label"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="some text " />
```

And here is the layout which has the id "frag5"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/frag5"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textfrag5label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Header:"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#FFFF4444"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    />



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textfrag5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="textt"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textfrag5label"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

**EDIT: activity_explain layout which is the layout of my ListView class**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:layout_weight=".50" />
```

Comment: Try returning a ```View``` in your fragment instead of ```ViewGroup rootView```

Comment: I tried ``` View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentdescrip6, container,false);
        return v; ``` but that did not work either.

Comment: Try using getChildFragmentManager() instead of getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: I think you should change the layout with id ```R.id.frag5``` to a framelayout

Comment: @AyushKhare since I am extending AppCompatActivity I can't access this method.

Comment: @ifiok I did it, but still same error.

Comment: The view with id frag5, is it a layout file of fragment class or your activity class? If it is a layout of your fragment class, then you must call getChildFragmentManager() instead of getSupportFragmentManager().

Comment: @SureshKumar Ok, but I can't access getChildFragmentManager() because I am not extending the Fragment class inside my listview class, I am extending AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id passed into `FragmentTransaction.replace()`, which, in your case is `R.id.frag5`, must be a child of the layout specified in `setContentView()` of the Activity.

Hence, for example, if your activity has a layout named `activity_main.xml`, then the `R.id.frag5` should be a child view inside it. If `R.id.frag` belongs to a different layout, then it is not recognised by `FragmentTransaction.replace()` and thus, the "No view found" error occurs.

**Edit with code example :-**

The entire idea of fragments is the reuse of space (hence, the `replace` or `add` functions)! So, for example, suppose that I have the following layout `activity_main.xml` :-

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/flbase"></FrameLayout>
    
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Hello!"/>
    
    

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, from my main activity, I can call the following code:-

```
Fragment fragToReplace = new Fragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager()
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.flbase,fragToReplace)
.commit();
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. But how to make R.id.frag5 a child view ? Could give a little code example please.

Comment: Yes it can! But, then you will have to obtain the view from the included layout and then proceed in the same manner as above.

Comment: So let us sum it up: I am in the class "ListView" and in its onCreate Method I have " setContentView(R.layout.activity_explain); " and activity_explain.xml DOES NOT include any other views or anything else, it just contains a listview. So I have to add FragmentLayout into activity_explain.xml and then call replace inside my ListView Class ?

Comment: No, that is incorrect. I understand your confusion, though.Think of it this way :- A fragment is an independent entity with a separate layout. In your case, that layout is `R.layout.fragmentdescrip6`. This is inflated in the fragment's `onCreateView()` method. So, wherever the fragment in your app is used, it'll have this very layout. 1/2

Comment: So, now, the whole point of this fragment stuff is that you can reuse the fragment and its functionality anywhere you like. All you need to have is a 'space' where the fragment can be put. That space is a view! In my answer, that 'space' is the `R.id.flbase`. And `.replace(R.id.flbase,fragToReplace)` puts the `fragToReplace` fragment in that space or view. There are several advantages to using fragments. You can easily replace this space with another fragment too. So you don't have to include each fragment's layout in your parent layout. 2/2

Comment: Ah, ok I understand. But the question is, how can I call this Fragment6 that inflates R.layout.fragmentdescrip6 ? It should be shown when I make a ListView Item Click. So  I am in `ListView.class` that has a `onCreate` method which does `setContentView(R.layout.activity_explain);` And now, I am going to add a `FrameLayout` in `activity_explain.xml` with the ID `frag5` and then calling the `replace` method ?

Comment: You must note that `setContentView()` is a method of the Activity.class and not ListView.class. So, you can forget about  the ListView.class for now. Your code in the question is absolutely correct. All you need to do is to add a `Framelayout` with the ID `frag5` in the layout of the activity that you created the listView object in.

Comment: Could you post your activity's layout?

Comment: Sure, I posted it

Comment: My ListView Class extends AppCompatActivity, just to inform you. I hope we can solve this, it is really important for me :)

Comment: So for testing, just put a `FrameLayout` anywhere inside your activity's layout and name it `frag5`. Then run your code again.

Comment: It really helped and worked. I appreciate your help and your patience and willing to help, really ;) I added the `FrameLayout` in my `activity_explain.xml` where also my ListView is, and when I set FrameLayouts width and height to `wrap_content` it overlaps my ListView, so that the ListView "dissapears". That's a bit tricky. Because now I have one ListView and one big FrameLayout in one layout.

Comment: No problem :). Glad I could help. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

There is no constructor in your `Fragment`. `Fragment` always requires empty constructor.

Please add this in your `Fragment6`

```
public Fragment6() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out your problem. You are trying to replace a Fragment to a child view of another fragment which is not yet added to your Activity. This will definitely lead to *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id* exception. Try to check if the Fragment which holds the view with id R.id.frag5 is added before you replace your Fragment to it.

Comment: What do you mean with "frag5 is added"  ? In my ListView Class setContentView is set to " setContentView(R.layout.activity_explain);" in onCreate Method.

Comment: Is there any view with id R.id.frag5 in your activity_explain?

Comment: No, nothing. My activity explain just has a Listview, that's it.

Comment: That exactly is the issue. I guess the view with id R.id.frag5 is a component of a fragment which is not yet added to your activity.

Comment: Yes, R.id.frag5 is the id of the framelayout inside "fragdescrip5.xml". and fragdescrip5.xml is inflated in Fragment5.class. How can I add this to my activity ?